# Android - Retrofit: Error getting a response. Gson error

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit, okhttp

I have setup an API in which I make calls via Retrofit.
I am new to Retrofit but I believe I am getting a response however I get a stacktrace when it triggers the onFailure().

I am using the API inside the MainActivity.class.

What does this mean, and how can I fix it.

Stacktrace:
http://pastebin.com/ADXhxsFP

Source Code:
https://github.com/Axiom1999/Iron-Banner-Companion/tree/master/app/src/main/java/me/axiom/aapp/ironbannercompanion

Gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
```

Comment: Your JSON has wrong syntax, that is the issue. Could you post the JSON response you got from server.

Comment: {"Response":"4611686018439042298","ErrorCode":1,"ThrottleSeconds":0,"ErrorStatus":"Success","Message":"Ok","MessageData":{}}

Comment: Well the JSON is valid, so I guess you are wrong POJO classes for converting the JSON.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DcD4kM05

Comment: And here is the BaseResponse class.

http://pastebin.com/9zt1sknE

Comment: OMG I am an idiot. Haha I tried to get a MAP and not a String. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed getting a response from the server.

Try to add a LoggingInterceptor so you increase the verbosity of the responses.
https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Also, I believe that you are trying to read a different JSON format than the one that API is giving you. Your IllegalStateException happens for example when the GSON converter tried to parse an object starting with a `{` but got `"` string instead (Search for that `"` in the column 14 of your API response).

See if you have the right POJOs to handle that request, if not you can create new ones with http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Thanks you @Evin1_ for replying. Here is the response I get from the server through Google Chrome.

{"Response":"4611686018439042298","ErrorCode":1,"ThrottleSeconds":0,"ErrorStatus":"Success","Message":"Ok","MessageData":{}}